# ABNT6023 Latex Referências Bibliográficas

Tags: latex, bibtex

Estou com uma dúvida referente a Latex, mais especificamente em normas da ABNT 6023:2018.
Gostaria de saber como posso alterar o ano de uma referência no arquivo Bibtex.

Exemplo:

```
@mastersthesis{alvesjoao2019,
  title={Um modelo preditivo de cotação de ações de empresas estatais brasileiras utilizando redes neurais artificiais no ambiente MATLAB},
  address={Uberlândia},
  author={ALVES, João Victor da Silva},
  year={2019},
  school={Universidade Federal de Uberlândia},
  type={Mestrado em Gestão Organizacional}
}
```

Terá a saída:

ALVES, J. V. d. S.**Um modelo preditivo de cotação de ações de empresas estatais brasileiras utilizando redes neurais artificiais no ambiente MATLAB**. 2019. Dissertação(Mestrado em Gestão Organizacional) — Universidade Federal de Uberlândia, Uberlândia, 2019.

Como pode-se ver existe dois anos de 2019, porém como posso alterar o segundo ano. Embora esse arquivo realmente tenha dois 2019, existem outras referências que tem datas diferentes, como posso alterar isso?

Comment: Vai depender da biblioteca utilizada e do modelo. Possui um [mcve] no Overleaf?